# Eval a function definition vs. variable function definition

Tags: javascript, function, scope, eval

If we define a `function f() { ... }` in `eval(...)`, why isn't it available for the rest of the code, such as #button3's onclick?

As a comparison, if we define the function as `f = () => { ... };`, then it is available for #button3's onclick.

Why this difference, which seems a little bit contradictory with [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) (here the idea is `function f() { ... }`  has a wider scope than `f = () => { ... };`).

Click 1 and 3 (`Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined`), and then 2 and 3 (working):

```js
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = () => eval("function f() { alert('hello'); }");
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = () => eval("f = () => { alert('hello'); };");
```

```html
<div id="button1">1 Click me to define f as a function</div>
<div id="button2">2 Click me to define f as a variable function</div>
<div id="button3" onclick="f();">3 Click to run f()</div>
```

Comment: 2 then 3 doesn't work for me - ReferenceError for `f`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I updated the snippet, now you can 2 then 3 working.

Comment: What do you get if you use *const* like: `const f = () =>` instead of just a Global `f = () =>`?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I haven't tested yet, but I tested `f = () => { };` working, `var f = () => { };` *not* working. Why?

Comment: @Basj CertainPerformance gave you an indepth answer

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, very interesting indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MDN says on `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

> `var`-declared variables and function declarations would go into the surrounding scope if the source string is not interpreted in strict mode — for indirect eval, they become global variables. If it's a direct eval in a strict mode context, or if the `eval` source string itself is in strict mode, then `var` and function declarations do not "leak" into the surrounding scope.

Here, you're using direct eval (because you're referencing `eval`) directly, and that "surrounding scope" is the inside of the click handler. To see this working, click, then see how the `function f` approach defines an `f` referenceable later in the click handler (but not outside of it):

```js
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = () => {
  eval("function f() { alert('hello'); }");
  f();
}

// scope doesn't extend to out here
setTimeout(() => console.log(typeof f), 3000);
```

```html
<div id="button1">1 Click me to define f as a function</div>
```

Doing

```
f = () => { ... };
```

is just like doing that in plain code, without `eval` - without declaring it with `const`, `let`, `var`, or `function`, you're implicitly assigning to the global object, so

```
eval("f = () => { alert('hello'); };");
```

is equivalent to

```
eval("window.f = () => { alert('hello'); };");
```

if no `f` variable exists in scope at that time.

```js
// runs
(() => {
  f = () => console.log('f');
})();
f();


// doesn't run
(() => {
  function g() {
    console.log('g');
  }
})();
g();
```

Inline handlers may only reference global variables (99% of the time), so for `onclick="f();"` to work, `window.f` must exist.

You're using direct eval. Note that if you used indirect eval, the evaled code won't run in the scope of where the `eval` reference was called, but rather on the top level - and as a result, any variable declaration inside such an eval will be visible everywhere.

```js
// both work
const indirectEval = eval;
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = () => indirectEval("function f() { alert('hello'); }");
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = () => indirectEval("f = () => { alert('hello'); };");
```

```html
<div id="button1">1 Click me to define f as a function</div>
<div id="button2">2 Click me to define f as a variable function</div>
<div id="button3" onclick="f();">3 Click to run f()</div>
```

Comment: Oh nice! Is it true in general that `f = "anything";` without let, const, var, function is equivalent to `window.f = "anything";`? Is there a canonical SO question/answer about this?

Comment: In sloppy mode, if `f` hasn't been defined yet, yes - it'll be added as a property to the global object. In strict mode (which is always recommended), trying to assign to a variable that hasn't been declared will instead throw an error. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488

Comment: (...and PS: modules are always treated as Strict Mode.) @Basj

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance! So if we want a `<div onclick="f();"` to access a function which is defined later with `eval`, the only solution is to define `f` as global?

Context: I'm inserting both this `<div onclick="f();">` and the `<script>` block in the DOM from the response of an AJAX call, with `container.innerHTML = ...`. Then I need to `eval()` the `<script>` as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml. Thus the `onclick="f();"` has to reference a function which is available here, thus this question. Any idea?

Comment: @Basj Yes, inline handlers may only reference global variables (leaving out the silly `with` scope they use that isn't worth thinking about). But this is for informative purposes only. If you're asking this in context of a real app, I'm quite sure there's a much, much better way to structure it, without relying on `eval` nor on inline handlers, both of which are pretty universally considered to be quite bad ideas.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, I know about these 2 usual facts (about eval and inline handlers). But I was curious about the limit of what we can do with them. More generally, how would you execute a script that is inserted in the DOM after an AJAX call and HTML fragment insertion? You wouldn't do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml/1197585#1197585?

Comment: @Basj I'd extract the text content inside the script tag, then [insert another script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58804758)